# which foot is forward on skatebaord

Tags: sports, foot

I'm a little bit confused which foot should be forward and which is back.

For example from [How to Determine If You Are Regular or Goofy Footed](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/how-to-find-your-skateboarding-stance-goofy-foot-vs-regular#how-to-determine-if-you-are-regular-or-goofy-footed):

> Skateboarders typically use their dominant foot as the back foot to
> make their skateboard easier to control.

But in this video: [THE SKATEBOARDING STANCES EXPLAINED!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjuBIiGC82s)
, it says contrary.

So, dominant foot should be back or forward?

Comment: There’s no “should”, it’s whatever feels “right”. I was normal-footed skateboarding and goofy-footed snowboarding for awhile, but I ended up normal-footed eventually :shrug:

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic. It may be on topic at sports.se.

Answer (score 2):

It is called goofy stance if you use your right foot in front. I am a goofy skater myself. It's the same on a snowboard. I don't think it is that uncommon.

Just do what feels natural.

See this article for more detail.

https://www.masterclass.com/articles/how-to-find-your-skateboarding-stance-goofy-foot-vs-regular#what-does-goofy-foot-mean-in-skateboarding

Comment: okay, question: which foot is dominant for regular and which for goofy?

Comment: I am not sure if this is general I am goofy and my right foot is dominant. Side note I also do weightlifting and expected my left foot to be dominant because of goofy but that was not the case. I cannot confirm whether this is the case for most people.

Comment: Dominant right foot forward. Not the statement says "Skateboarders TYPICALLY use their dominant foot as the back foot to make their skateboard easier to control.". I am not sure how many people skate this way.